# Correct way of creating a realtime application with Cassandra

Tags: database, amazon-ec2, server, cassandra, nosql

Right now I have a ec2 instance running Cassandra and a simple websocket server.  I would like to know if this is the correct way to make a "real time" chat application. Is there anything I'm missing?

Client connects to websocket, inserts a message, the message is stored into database, and the message is then sent to users if the record to the database is successful.

```
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
const client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['127.0.0.1'], 
localDataCenter: 'datacenter1' });

const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 3000 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {

   //Insert message into Cassandra DB
   //Send message to other users if record to database with a consistency 
      level of one is successful
   //Then send messages to users connected to the websocket in chatroom

});
```

Edit: I also can't seem to find any tutorials on something like this so if you have any links please share

Comment: Can you specify for what purposes you persist messages? In nutshell you architecture is okayish, cause Cassandra handles high load writes very well, but when we are talking about reading there are some nuances.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by "what purposes you persist messages"? I chose cassandra because I am trying to make a realtime chat application like twitch with alot of users writing. But I don't know if the way I show above is the correct way to use websockets with a database.

Comment: as I understand your idea:
1. User send message
2. Message is stored in DB
3. Message is sent to another users in chat.

What would change if you remove point 2?

Comment: Yes you are correct, that is what I am trying to do. But I cannot find any example on the web of anyone doing it this way with websocket, so I am wondering if the way I do it is wrong

Comment: https://medium.com/@martin.sikora/node-js-websocket-simple-chat-tutorial-2def3a841b61 
This would be ok?)

Comment: Haha I already saw that article and learned how to create websocket with node, but what it's missing is how to handle queries to the database, how to manage all the user connection instances, and he also says this: "It’s all relatively new. I haven’t seen many real applications in Node.js. Just a bunch of games and some nice demos.". So since many real applications don't use it, what do companies use?

Comment: In case "just resend messages to current online users" DB is obsolete. So this is initial question - for what purposes you need database? For cache? For history? For message analysis?

Comment: Oh I understand what you meant. Yeah it would be for history, just recording the message logs in database

Answer (score 4):

There is no simple answer to your question and it is not very clear what is about.
'if record in db is successful' is not an easy thing in context of distributed systems like Cassandra, because you can have many replicas of your data. It is always a tradeoff between data consistency and availability. First of all you need to understand the [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) before using Cassandra.

I'm not sure that the chat app reuires strong consistency, but it will be good to have 2 or 3 replicas of data. In case of cassandra you can choose more suitable [consistency level](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/architecture/dynamo.html#tunable-consistency). I think for chat massages it can be `ONE` or `ANY`, in this case Csaandra will provide evantually consistency, but you will have more availability and performance in comparison with more 'strong'consistency levels.

Comment: I am trying to make a realtime chat application like twitch where consistency does not require strong consistency. I am just unsure if using websockets and cassandra is the correct choice because I don't know what is the correct tools to use to make a application like that

Comment: Websockets is a good technology for real time messaging, I don't know any modern alternatives for it. Cassandra can be too complicated for a simple chat application and too expensive in support and maintanence, it requires specific knowladges and skills. I would recommend to consider AWS services e.g. DynamoDB, due to DynamoDB provided as a service, it does not require maintenance and support from your side, you can just use it.

Comment: Yeah I actually found 0 examples with websocket + cassandra. And none on how to make a realtime application using Cassandra. I know dynamoDB is  good, but this is more of a learning experience on how to build it you know what I mean?

Comment: In context of 'realtime' I would also recommend you to consider rxjs (https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/overview) library which will allow you to simplify asynchronous code by using reactive paradigm. I belive you can find some examples on the web how to use it with node.js and web sockets.

Answer (score 4):

Pros of Cassandra for your purpose.

1. Cassandra is good at handling high load writes due to using of LSM
   trees.
2. Cassandra is **relatively** simple to maintain as distributed
   storage. From one side unlike RDBMS Cassandra has inbox replication, consistency levels, etc. From another side unlike Hbase Cassandra nodes has same ranks(no Masters, Region servers, etc).

Cons of Cassandra.

1. If there is no high load Cassandra is a huge overhead in comparison with single-node RDBMS solution either in terms of hardware consumption(especially RAM), or in maintainability.
2. Cassandra in distributed mode has so-called `eventual consistency`. In nutshell it sounds ok, but sometimes there are issues in ordering of rows, which may be crucial for your chat history. Here is an link to the article https://aphyr.com/posts/299-the-trouble-with-timestamps that is old, but just to explain the general idea.
3. You are bounded to initial data model. Any read queries with where clauses that includes fields that are not in primary/clustering key are unperformant. SQL support is really poor with limitation of any aggregation queries, etc.

I believe items above are good to take in mind during system design.